# Determining Workflow Arguments at Runtime Prior to Execution

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is there a way to determine the arguments to a workflow prior to executing it?

I've developed an application that rehosts the designer, so end users can develop their own workflows. In doing this, a user is able to add their own arguments to the workflow.

I'm looking for a way to inspect the workflow prior to execution, and try to resolve the arguments. I've looked at the `WorkflowInspectionServices` class, but I can't seem to ask for a particular type of item from it.

Ideally, I'd like to construct a workflow from metadata stored in the database using something like:

```
var workflow = ActivityXamlServices.Load(new XamlReader(new StringReader(xamlText)));
var metadata = SomeUnknownMagicClass.Inspect(workflow);

var inputs = new Dictionary<string, object>()
forreach(var argument in metadata.Arguments)
{
    inputs.Add(argument.Name, MagicArgumentResolver.Resolve(argument.Name));
}

WorflowInvoker.Invoke(workflow, inputs);
```

I might be missing something, but `WorkflowInspectionServices` doesn't seem to do this. It has the method `CacheMetadata` which sounds promising when you read the MSDN docs, but basically turns up with nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that when you talk about *metadata stored in the database* you're referring to the XAML from the designer.

You can load that XAML as a *[DynamicActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity.aspx)* like this:

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(xamlString))
{
    var dynActivity = 
        ActivityXamlServices.Load(reader) as DynamicActivity;
}
```

Then you've access to all its arguments through *[DynamicActivity.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.dynamicactivity.properties.aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks, Jota. Stupidly, I'd actually already looked at the DynamicActivity with regard to the CacheMetadata call, but completely overlooked the Properties collection. And yes, I meant the XAML markup stored as text in a blob. Thanks again.